# Как изменить посредник аунтификации api в laravel

Tags: laravel, middleware

Я новичок в laravel и покопавшись в доках и на форуме, поискав во фреймворке и попробовав что-то покодить пришел в тупик.
Мне нужно, чтобы посредник авторизации api laravel при получении запроса проверял не только api_token, но и login, а также в случае если эти данные неуспешны не делал redirect на страницу login а возвращал определенный статус.
Где это можно изменить или нужно создавать отдельный посредник и вставлять его в kernel?
Буду рад примерам кода.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариантов несколько:

1) Написать полностью новый middleware

2) Расширить мидлвар аутентификации. Http/Middleware/Authenticate .

3) Добавить свой guard : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#adding-custom-guards

Comment: А как реализовать 2 вариант ? Проверять в Authenticate какой guard передан и если api там же реализовывать проверку ?

Comment: Примерно так. Откройте родителя, там есть метод handle расширьте или переопределите его в Http/Middleware/Authenticate .